# Check if Spring Multipart File uploaded has a form field

Tags: spring, spring-boot, file-upload, multipartform-data

We were using the apache file uploads for uploading a file and below code was used for the same.

```
 ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(itemFactory);

        List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);

        Iterator<FileItem> iterator = items.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = iterator.next();

            if (item.isFormField()) {
                String name = item.getFieldName();
                String value = item.getString();
                conf.put(name, value);
            } else {
                InputStream is = item.getInputStream();
                byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(is);
                String query = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                conf.put("test", query);
            }
        }
```

But we recently moved to Spring boot and trying to use spring multipart to upload a file.The code which will replace the above code will be

```
        DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest requestMain = (DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
        Iterator<String> fileNameIterator = requestMain.getFileNames();
        ListIterator<MultipartFile> iterator = null;
        while (fileNameIterator.hasNext()) {
            multipartFiles = requestMain.getFiles(fileNameIterator.next());
            iterator = multipartFiles.listIterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                MultipartFile item = iterator.next();
                if (item.isEmpty()) {
                    // String name = item.getFieldName();
                    // String value = item.getString();
                    // conf.put(name, value);
                } else {
                    InputStream is = item.getInputStream();
                    byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(is);
                    String query = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                    conf.put("query", query);
                }
            }

        }
```

But I am not able to figure out how to check if the file has a form field in spring boot.In apache file upload it was achieved using `item.isFormField()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check if the item is form field.
The `requestMain.getFiles(fileNameIterator.next());` method will return a `MultipartFile` so you know is not a form field.

To get the form fields use

```
requestMain.getParameterMap()
```

Or, for a specific field use

```
requestMain.getParameter("field")
```